# Using storyboard to create multiple TableViews that can be toggled between using a button

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm trying to create an app where multiple lists can be switched between using a button. Does anyone have any advice on the best way to do this, preferably using storyboard (my Swift skills leave a lot to be desired)? Right now I only have one list (a TableView) which is contained in a Container View, along with two other regular Views, one at the top and one at the bottom of the Container View, with the TableView in the middle. I want to have a button in the top regular View that switches between multiple TableViews. I want the number of TableViews to be dynamic, starting with one, but then the user can add additional tables as they need. Any advice on how to set this up would be greatly appreciated! Is it even possible to create a prototype TableView? Is that the way to go here? I've found a couple of Answers on Stack Overflow regarding multiple tables on a single screen, but these lists wouldn't be on a single screen, they would only be viewable one at a time: if you want to see the second list, you have to press the "Next List" button (in the View at the top of the Container View), and the first list disappears and is replaced with the second. Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 1):

Don't change table views, change datasources.  Use a single table view as you have it, and one array for each mode that the table is in (call those `arrayA` and `arrayB`).  Another array-type variable -- call it `theModel` -- should be set to point to A or B.

The datasource methods will answer the count of `theModel`, and get values for the cells from `theModel`.  When the user presses the button...

```
self.theModel = (self.theModel== self.arrayA)? self.arrayB : self.arrayA
self.tableView.reloadData()
// everywhere else, use theModel as the datasource
```